# Get property of a token object in powershell Object

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-5.1

Working in Powershell 5.1

I'm getting a bearer token but I'm unable to grab that property of this Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject .

If I write-host of the $token I get

```
{"access_token":"123123123123123","expires_in":300,"refresh_expires_in":0,"token_type":"Bearer","not-before-policy":0,"scope":"
profile email"}
```

but I just want the Access-token, so I been trying

```
write-host $($token."access_token")
write-host $($token.access_token)
write-host $token."access_token"
```

And a lot more but I been only been getting blanks, Does anyone know the solution to this, I only want the value of access_token?

Comment: your `$token` looks like a plain Json. Did you try `$token | ConvertFrom-Json` ?

Comment: It looks like you are using `Invoke-WebRequest`, which only gives you the raw server response. Try to use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#outputs) instead, which automatically parses the JSON response into a PowerShell object.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below to access the accessToken property-

```
$token = az account get-access-token  | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty accessToken
```

Then,

```
$Headers = @{
'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $token
```

}

I had the similar issue.